How do i fix this wierd problem with my xbox one controller
As seen in the title im having issues with my xbox one controller.
Literally every time im trying to use it, it just flips me off by turning off automatically, disconnecting and Reconnecting and doing wierd Rumble, even tho i always disable rumble in any game i play.
I looked far and wide but i couldnt find any fix, since xpad and xboxdrv arent able to identify the controller at all.
Does someone have the same issue or an fix?
Please let me know because right now im really desperate.

Are you even using a supported Ubuntu release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
